# WCF Service Hosted in ASP.NET website - Windows Authentication not working

Tags: asp.net, windows, wcf, authentication, iis

I am hosting a WCF service in an asp.net website. On IIS it has integrated windows authentication setting. I'm making call to wcf service method from one of the asp.net website pages using jquery. But, unfortunately, that call is asking for windows username/password which I already provided for the website. My understanding is the authentication token will be automatically passed to the wcf call as well.

Please let me know if there is something wrong with my configuration/ajax call.

The following is my configuration:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EllipseBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EllipseBehavior" >
      <!-- Add the following element to your service behavior configuration. -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="EllipseService" behaviorConfiguration="EllipseBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="XX.Services.Behaviour.EllipseBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" contract="XX.Services.Contract.IEllipseService" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>

  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>

</client>
```

**Ajax call**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Services/Ellipse.svc/GetWorkOrdersByLine",
        data: { lineCode: workOrder.getLineCode() },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        statusCode: {
            404: function() {
                alert("Incorrect URI for Service Orders");
                $.unblockUI();
            }
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: this.onSuccess,
        error: this.onError
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the 'TransportCredentialOnly' attribute in your binding. This article explains it pretty well:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx

**How to: Use basicHttpBinding with Windows Authentication and TransportCredentialOnly in WCF from Windows Forms**

> This how-to article walks you through the process of using Windows
>   authentication over the basicHttpBinding binding using the
>   TransportCredentialsOnly security mode. The article shows you how to
>   configure WCF, configure Internet Information Services (IIS) for
>   Windows authentication, and test the service with a sample WCF client.